# Validación de datos en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Para un proyecto de la escuela necesito crear objetos de tipo Alumno, pidiendo que se ingresen los datos en un textPane de Swing

```
    int id;
    int edad;
    int cali;
    String nombre;
    String apellidoPaterno;
    String apellidoMaterno;
    String correo;
    boolean crearAlumno = false;
    if(!"".equals(jTextPane5.getText()) && !"".equals(jTextPane6.getText()) && !"".equals(jTextPane8.getText())
    && !"".equals(jTextPane7.getText()) && !"".equals(jTextPane9.getText()) && !"".equals(jTextPane10.getText())
    && !"".equals(jTextPane11.getText())){
        try{
            nombre = jTextPane5.getText();
            apellidoPaterno =jTextPane6.getText();
            apellidoMaterno = jTextPane7.getText();
            correo = jTextPane10.getText();
            id = Integer.parseInt(jTextPane9.getText());
            edad = Integer.parseInt(jTextPane8.getText());
            cali = Integer.parseInt(jTextPane11.getText());
            crearAlumno = true;
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        if(crearAlumno){
            Persona nuevoAlumno = new Alumno(id, nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, correo, edad, cali);
            materiaSeleccionada.alumnos.add((Alumno)nuevoAlumno);
            modeloListaAlumnos.addElement(nuevoAlumno.nombreCompleto());
            todosAlumnos.add((Alumno)nuevoAlumno);
            menuMateria.setVisible(true);
            menuAlumno.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("Estos son todos los alumnos que existen en el sistema:" + todosAlumnos);

            jTextPane5.setText("");
            jTextPane6.setText("");
            jTextPane7.setText("");
            jTextPane10.setText("");
            jTextPane9.setText("");
            jTextPane8.setText("");
            jTextPane11.setText("");
        }
    } else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Llena todos los datos", "InfoBox: " + "Error:", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Primero creo las variables id, edad, calificación, nombre, etc.
Después si todos los campos estan llenos, procedo a la asignación del contenido de cada textPane a su respectiva variable, y si el usuario pone todos los datos de acuerdo a su tipo, cambia la variable de crearAlumno a true para proseguir a la creaciòn del alumno. Si algo falla, se sale del try y nunca cambia la variable booleana, por lo que no crea al alumno nunca.

El programa me marca que "es posible que las variables para la creación de alumno no estén asignadas a algún valor, pero según yo ya tome las medidas para que solo se cree el alumno si estan llenas las variables.

Saludos, y perdón si no está bien explicado, primera vez que publico aqui :)

Comment: de que manera el programa te dice ese mensaje , con los warnings ? , PD: (son unas alertas amarillas) , estas ocupando eclipse o algo por el estilo?, tu programa tiene algún error al correrlo?.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código debería funcionar.

El aviso que te sale, que no error, es porque solo inicializas las variables dentro del bloque `try`, con lo que en un hipotético caso en el que no se detiene la ejecución del programa al saltar la excepción (no deberías esconder los fallos), las variables estarían a `null`, `false` o `0`.

```
String cadena;
try {
    cadena = leerLineaDeFichero();    // Método hipotético
} catch (IOException e) {
    ;    // No hacemos nada
}
int longitud = cadena.length();    // Posible NullPointerException
```

Como ejemplo, tenemos una cadena de caracteres `cadena`, que por defecto no hace referencia a ninguna cadena en realidad (la JVM inicializa los objetos a `null`).

Imagina ahora que leemos una cadena de un fichero mediante el método `leerLineaDeFichero()`, pero hay un error de disco, por ejemplo al desconectar el usb donde se encontraba el fichero que queremos leer.

En ese caso, salta una excepción de tipo `IOException`.

Como ves, en el cuerpo del `catch` solo hay comentarios, y una sentencia vacía (el punto y coma `;`).

Normalmente, gracias a la sentencia `e.printStrackTrace()` la ejecución del programa se detiene, pero al quitarla, el error se oculta, y la ejecución continúa.

Cuando intentamos invocar a cualquier método sobre la variable `cadena` salta un `NullPointerException` porque dicha variable no hace referencia a ningún objeto que pueda ejecutar dicho método.

La solución, sin embargo, es muy sencilla: dale un valor antes del `try`. Si estás seguro de que controlas bien las excepciones, puedes incluso darle un valor `null` a dichas variables, lo que es absurdo porque ya lo hace la JVM por defecto.

```
String cadena = null;    // Solucionado
try {
    cadena = leerLineaDeFichero();    // Método hipotético
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();    // No escondamos los posibles fallos
}
int longitud = cadena.length();
```

Creo que es para que si le das un valor nulo a una variable sea de manera explícita y los `NullPointerEception` culpa del programador de turno.

Answer (score 0):

Guiándome más por el titulo la validación que estas haciendo en los respectivos `if`si quieres asegurarte de que los `getText()` vengan con algo puedes también validar que sean distintos de `null`.

```
if(jTextPane5.getText() != null && !"".equals(jTextPane5.getText()) && jTextPane6.getText() != null && !"".equals(jTextPane6.getText()) 
&& jTextPane8.getText()  != null &&!"".equals(jTextPane8.getText())
&& jTextPane7.getText()  != null && !"".equals(jTextPane7.getText()) 
&& jTextPane9.getText()  != null && !"".equals(jTextPane9.getText()) 
&& jTextPane10.getText() != null && !"".equals(jTextPane10.getText())
&& jTextPane11.getText() != null && !"".equals(jTextPane11.getText())){
```

ya con los if que tienes no deberías tener problema alguno

Comment: Lo que quiero es:
1.- Que todos los campos esten llenos antes de la asignación de variables.
2.- Que los valores que estan en los campos TENGAN que ser del tipo que yo quiero.

Eso es lo que no se hacer

Comment: 1.- R: Para que estén inicializados antes de la asignación lo puedes hacer dependiendo del tipo de dato de la variable y lo que necesites que tenga inicializado, las 7 variables que declaras al principio con que necesitas inicializarlas? 2.- R: no entiendo que quieres decir con eso, en el código las variables ya le estas asignando un tipo de dato.

Comment: @AndresAbimeri, en la pregunta dices que el programa te dice que las variables aún no son inicializadas, mi pregunta es estas usando NETBEANS?, te pregunto esto por que los editores de código te avisan que tienes posibles problemas pero esto no quiere decir que tu código no funcione, solo son avisos, claramente si este es el caso no tendrías ningún inconveniente en ocupar el código tal y como esta.